# Python 3.7 Error When Using Wavefile to Read a .wav File

Tags: python

I'm very new to using python, and I encountered an error when trying to fix a problem with some of my code. The code analyzes the frequency of sound and compares it to gunshots, but I keep getting an error. Unfortunately, I was not able to fix it on my own, although I spent several hours trying to do so.

This is the problematic part of my code:

```
import wave    
from wave import *
import scipy
from scipy import *
from scipy.io import wavfile as wav
import os
from os import *

os.path.join('/Users/TheBigApple/Downloads/make_call.py', '/Users/TheBigApple/Downloads/gun-gunshot-01.wav')
os.path.join('/Users/TheBigApple/Downloads/make_call.py', '/Users/TheBigApple/Downloads/machine-gun-02.wav')
os.path.join('/Users/TheBigApple/Downloads/make_call.py', '/Users/TheBigApple/Downloads/machine-gun-01.wav')
os.path.join('/Users/TheBigApple/Downloads/make_call.py', '/Users/TheBigApple/Downloads/Prepared SFX Library/1911/A_34P.wav')
os.path.join('/Users/TheBigApple/Downloads/make_call.py', '/Users/TheBigApple/output.wav') 


CHUNK = 1087
FORMAT = pyaudio.paInt16
CHANNELS = 1
WAVE_OUTPUT_FILENAME = "output.wav"
RATE = 2000
RECORD_SECONDS = 10
p = pyaudio.PyAudio()
wf = wave.open("output.wav", 'wb')
stream = p.open(format=FORMAT,
                channels=CHANNELS,
                rate=RATE,
                input=True,
                frames_per_buffer=CHUNK,
                output=True)
frames = []

for i in range(0, int(RATE / CHUNK * RECORD_SECONDS)):
    data = stream.read(CHUNK)
frames.append(data)

data = scipy.io.wavfile.read("output.wav")

wf.setnchannels(1)
wf.setsampwidth(p.get_sample_size(FORMAT))
wf.setframerate(RATE)
wf.close()
```

On this line:

```
    data = scipy.io.wavfile.read('output.wav'):
```

I get the following error:

```
/Users/TheBigApple/PycharmProjects/untitled1/venv/bin/python /Users/TheBigApple/Downloads/make_call.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/TheBigApple/Downloads/make_call.py", line 206, in <module>
    data = scipy.io.wavfile.read("output.wav")
  File "/Users/TheBigApple/PycharmProjects/untitled1/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/scipy/io/wavfile.py", line 236, in read
    file_size, is_big_endian = _read_riff_chunk(fid)
  File "/Users/TheBigApple/PycharmProjects/untitled1/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/scipy/io/wavfile.py", line 168, in _read_riff_chunk
    "understood.".format(repr(str1)))
ValueError: File format b''... not understood.

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: did you try to open "output.wav" in some player ? Maybe it is not correct wav file.

Comment: maybe you shouldn't read file before you write and close it.

Comment: Thank you very much for your suggestions. I really appreciate your help.  I did try to open the file and play it; it does seem to be a .wav file. It also seems to be the correct wav file in my program (the same error occurred once I changed its name). Do you know of any other .wav reading modules in python that could analyze the file?

Comment: it is strage that you can open it because `wave.open("output.wav", 'wb')` should open file for writing so it should create new empty file and your error should stop script before it can close it - `wf.close()`. And I don't see you write anything in this file. Maybe you have two `output.wav` - in code I see path `'/Users/TheBigApple/output.wav'` but script probably creates and reads file in folder `Downloads` - `/Users/TheBigApple/Downloads/output.wav`

Comment: Thank you again for your help.  The reason why I can open it (I think) is that another part of my code created the file; earlier, I had received the no such file or dir error, and that was how I knew to fix it. Yes, I think the problem was that I had the file as 'wb'. (I did need it to be wb because I wrote on it in a part of the code I did not show.) Fortunately, I simply copied the file and made that 'rb', which seems to have solved the problem.